document.body.innerHTML set in JSDOM ignored by implementation
Here is my TS code:
export class MyClass {
  private myElement: HTMLElement;
  constructor() {
    this.myElement = document.getElementById("ID") as HTMLElement;
    if (!this.myElement) {
      throw new Error("myElement is missing")
    }
  }
}

Here is my Jest test:
it("should not throw an error", () => {
  document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='ID'>some text</div>";
  const sut = new MyClass();
});

Here is my jest.config.js:
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom"
}

My package.json:
{
...
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
  "jest": "^29.7.0",
  "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
  "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
  "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
  "typescript": "^5.4.2",
  "webpack": "^5.90.3",
  "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
}
}

For some reason, the div I create in my unit test seems to be ignored and the implementation throws an error: "myElement is missing".
Can anyone spot the issue with my setup? Thank you in advance!

You're setting it as a text, maybe you should try with document.createElement('div') and then appending it to the body

@Teneff Thanks! I've also tried that but got the same result unfortunately.

Just a heads up... if you assign the getElementById result to a local, check for null and throw an error, you do not need the cast to assign it to the instance property after: TS is smart enough to narrow the type from HTMLElement | null to just HTMLElement after the conditional throw

Unable to reproduce. Your code works fine for me on Ubuntu 22.04, assuming I import the file:
t.test.ts:
import { MyClass } from "./t";

it("should not throw an error", () => {
  document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='ID'>some text</div>";
  const sut = new MyClass();
  expect(document.querySelector("#ID").textContent).toBe("some text");
});

t.ts:
export class MyClass {
  private myElement: HTMLElement;
  constructor() {
    this.myElement = document.getElementById("ID") as HTMLElement;
    if (!this.myElement) {
      throw new Error("myElement is missing")
    }
  }
}

package.json:
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "typescript": "^5.4.2",
    "webpack": "^5.90.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}

jest.config.js:
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom"
}

Run:
$ npm i
$ npm run test

> test
> jest

ts-jest[config] (WARN) message TS151001: If you have issues related to imports, you should consider setting `esModuleInterop` to `true` in your TypeScript configuration file (usually `tsconfig.json`). See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/01/31/announcing-typescript-2-7/#easier-ecmascript-module-interoperability for more information.
 PASS  ./t.test.ts
  ✓ should not throw an error (11 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.072 s
Ran all test suites.


Thank you!
I got frustrated and rewrote the entire thing. Now, it works without any issues.
TBH, I still don't know what my issue was as I cannot spot a difference in my "new" implementation. I was banging my head against a wall all morning...

Thanks for confirming. If you do figure it out, feel free to share it, since it could be helpful to future visitors.
